# Solaris10 , disk io sar -d output interpretation

Tags: solaris, disk, sar

Question: in sar -d output ..you have %busy column. How is this value calculated? can this value be more than 100%?

Answer (score 0):

> How is this value calculated?

This is the percentage of time the device is being read from or written to.

> Can it be more than 100%?

No, technically it shouldn't ever be possible for it to be greater than 100%, It can be 100% but this just means that the disk was doing 100% IO operation for the measurement interval.

Being 100% however is not necessarily a bad thing. If you are looking for disk bottle necks you should be more interested in the other stats `sar` provides  `await`,`rd_sec/s`,`wr_sec/s`...etc

Comment: device %busy avque r+w/s blks/s avwait avserv
sd5 171 474.2 472 13333 158.7 846
sd5,a 0 0 0 0 0 0
sd5,b 0 0 0 0 0 0
sd5,c 0 0 0 0 0 0
sd5,d 0 0 0 0 0 0
sd5,e 166 28 0 0 0 0
sd5,f 241 21.2 5 4867 1442.1 3026.3
sd5,g 0 0 0 0 0 0
sd5,h 171 440.3 469 9878 136.8 802.8
when i look at the sar data it looks like this..it has values 171..